# Eclipse execute a file in jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse product. In my plugin i have added an executable file (.exe) which i need to execute. When i launch the product from the eclipse, the file is referenced using the path of the executable on my file system and all went ok.

When i export the product the plugin is packaged in a jar file which contains the executable file too. When it references the file the path is something like :

```
$path_to_the_plugin_jar!/$path_to_exe_file_inside_the_jar
```

Using this path to launch a new Process Thrown an exception.

How can i refer to a file inside a jar?How could i execute the file?

Can i extract the file when i export the product with eclipse?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

I solved, as  Konstantin Komissarchik suggested, by converting the product from plugin-based to feature-based and by specify in the feature.xml file the "Unpack...." for the plugin.

When I export the product, the plugin is exploded in a folder and I can refer the files I need.

Answer (score 3):

EXE files need to be executed by Windows.  For all practical purposes a jar file is a zip-file, so you basically need to figure out how to have Windows run a EXE-file in a ZIP-file.

To my knowledge no such facility exist, so you must extract the EXE-file to a temporary location, and run it from there.

Comment: Alternatively, you can mark the plugin to be exploded on install. You do this in your feature. You will have a plugin dir instead of plugin jar in that case.

Comment: thanks for the hint!this should be probably the solution..but how could i tell ecplipse to explode the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Before executing you could unpack the file to the bundles-state location.
something like that:

```
InputStream stream = FileLoactor.openStream(myBundle, new Path("path/to/exe/")
IPath pathUnpacked = myBundle.getStateLocation().append("myExe.exe");
writeToDisk(stream, pathUnpacked);
Program.launch(pathUnpacked.toOSString());
```

HTH Tom